# How to include java class files as plugins run from an external folder in a program

Tags: java, class, plugins, classloader, external

I'm currently making a terminal/command prompt type program for my college work and I'd like to include a separate folder in the documents library called "plugins" where i can create new class files and put them in there to add new features and functionality to my program without having to edit the source code of it. I've Tried using classloaders but I'm not sure how i can use this to run methods from within the external .java files. Is this possible to do and could anybody help me out?

thanks in advance

Comment: Why can't you package them into a JAR and add them as a dependency to your project?  It'll help if you have a common interface that they all implement.

Comment: Or put the directory on your classpath?

Comment: Using either of these two solutions does that mean i could have the program automatically scan for new plugins and add/use them while running the program?

Comment: If it’s your program, why can’t you recompile it and rerun it as you add new classes?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what are you trying to achieve with this. I suposse is some kind of plugin system. Usually that is not the right way to obtain flexibility. If you post more details, the answer could be more accurate.

There are two different problems here.

First, you want to load class from a folder outside our program. You can modify the classpath of your program to load that classes at RUNTIME. You need to modify the manifest file in your program.

Second, you want to use the loaded classes in your program. That is a different beast. If you use Spring framework, one way to achieve this is that the jars in the outside folder comes with a well-known xml file where the classes to use get injected as beans. Other way to achieve this is make a custom annotation and inject te classes using reflection.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by hand or with a framework, depending on your needs. If your project is more than a toy project, use a framework.

*Warning: I did this kind of things once (by hand). I wouldn't do it anymore unless I think my application will be widely disseminated and used by very different people. If you want to add sometimes a new feature, just add it, recompile and ship the new version.*

*Warning2: In both cases, you will have to think to security issues (how to build a sandbox?), conflicts (if two plugins use the same resource, what should your application do?) and dependencies (if your plugin depends on an external library or on other plugins, how to load them?).*

## With a Framework

I found [this](https://github.com/pf4j/pf4j) that sounds promising and uses annotations, but there are many other possiblities (I never used [OSGi](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSGi) but why not?).

## By hand

I give you a sketch; in a real project, it could be more sophisticated. I'll ignore security issues.

### Big Picture

You have to define some hooks in the normal course of your application. Every hook is associated with an action. Classic example: before a file is saved, your application calls the  `beforeSave` hook, that is a `beforeSave` method, or when your application creates a menu, it calls a `addNewItems` method. The application has the responsibility to load the plugins. The plugins have the responsibility to execute the actions.

The best way to understand this mechanism is to take a look at some PHP CMS: MediaWiki, Wordpress, ... are built on this model.

### At compile time

Your application has hooks that correspond to some method calls. Those method calls are handled by plugins. Thus you have to create a contract between your application and those plugins. In Java, this contract will be one or more interface(s) which defines the methods that:

- your application will call
- your plugins will implement.

Obviously, this (these) interface(s) is (are) known by every plugin and your application, *at compile time* (you should include it in your application and in every plugin).

### At runtime

#### Initialization: loading the plugins

Your plugins are jars containing some classes which implement one or more interfaces. For every jar in the plugin directory, you have to list the classes that implements one or many of the interfaces, and choose the one(s) that will be loaded and instantiated.

It can be done in a few steps:

1. Your application scans the plugin directory and creates a `JarFile` object for every jar file.
2. For every `JarEntry`, if the jar entry ends with `.class`, then the application builds the class name and load the class with the class loader (`ClassLoader.loadClass`).
3. If the class implements one of the interfaces, the application stores the class.
4. Your application has now a map that associates a set of classes to every interface.

Then you need a mechanism to define a priority if many classes implement the same interface, resolve conflicts and dependencies. For priorities, this can be a config file, a priority value defined by the interface itself, the name of the classes (01 before 02), ... You choose, for every interface that is implemented, the right class(es) and load it (them) for real (`ClassLoader.forName`), then instantiate it (and the dependencies).

Some libraries may help you with reflection: I like [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/ReflectionExplained).

#### When the application comes across a hook

Now, you have one or more instances of classes that implement the interface. Every time your application comes across a hook, it checks if there is an object that it may use. If it is the case, it calls the method corresponding to the hook.

As said, this is just for a toy project, but it should work. You can add security checks, plugin load/unload, etc.